# How do I deploy a Front- and Backend applicaton to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm, directory

I am using ReactJS as my Frontend and NodeJS as my Backend of my application and I found the [buildpack](https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node) called heroku-cra-node. I followed the tutorial on the github repo and changed my `package.json` to the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "cd backend && npm install && node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd .. && cd frontend/ && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  }
```

**Note:** My folder structure looks like this (everything with subfolders):

```
app/
├── backend/
└── frontend/
```

When I start running `git push heroku master` I get the following error message.

```
remote: sh: 1: cd: can't cd to frontend/
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 2
remote: npm ERR! app@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `cd .. && cd frontend/ && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 2
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the app@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
```

How can I get back out of the backend folder to the app and then cd into the frontend again?

Comment: Please clarify what you want help with and the problem you encountered in more detail

Comment: same problem internet friend....  any luck solving it?

Comment: @Alexis from what I saw it's not possible to run two deployments under the same project. You might want to test deploying your front-end and back-end to two different projects